# "the attribute name used by the class to hold a descriptor takes precedence over attributes stored on instances" - What does this mean?

Tags: python, instance, descriptor

While reading Descriptors from "Python Essential Reference, Fourth Edition, David M Beazley", a certain example is provided to clarify how the fetch and update operations work for instance attributes using descriptors. The following is the example that is provided -

```
class TypedProperty(object):
    def __init__(self,name,type,default=None):
        self.name = "_" + name
        self.type = type
        self.default = default if default else type()
    def __get__(self,instance,cls):
        return getattr(instance,self.name,self.default)
    def __set__(self,instance,value):
        if not isinstance(value,self.type):
            raise TypeError("Must be a %s" % self.type)
        setattr(instance,self.name,value)
    def __delete__(self,instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute")
        
class Foo(object):
    name = TypedProperty("name",str)
    num = TypedProperty("num",int,42)
    
f = Foo()
a = f.name
f.name = "Guido"
```

While explaining this above sample the following statement is made - "the attribute name used by the class to hold a descriptor takes precedence over attributes stored on instances. In the previous example, this is why the descriptor object takes a name parameter and why the name is changed slightly by
inserting a leading underscore. In order for the descriptor to store a value on the
instance, it has to pick a name that is different than that being used by the descriptor
itself.". I am not clear as to what it means.

To understand what might happen if in TypedProperty **init**() the leading underscore was not added I changed the line to

```
self.name = name
```

That causes my program to crash whenever I try to view f.name. So can someone please explain the order of scopes or namespaces in which name is searched when f.name is viewed or set.